# How to check/uncheck dynamically created checkboxes in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

I have this code:

```
 public void CreateCheckBox(int i)
 {
      foreach (ListItem item in listItems.Items)
      {
          CheckBox box = new CheckBox();

          box.Enabled = true;
          box.AutoPostBack = true;
          box.EnableViewState = true;
          box.ID = string.Format("Active_{0}", item.Value);
          box.Text = "Active";
          box.CssClass = "checkbox_format2";

          if (chkSetAllActive.Checked)
          {
              box.Checked = true;
              box.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(CheckedChange);
          }
          else
          {
             box.Checked = false;
             box.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(CheckedChange);
          }
          PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(box);
}

protected void CheckedChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        CheckBox x = (CheckBox)sender;
        if (chkSetAllActive.Checked)
            x.Checked = true;
        else
            x.Checked = false; 
}
```

and in `PageLoad()` I call this

```
CreateCheckBox(listItems.Items.Count);
```

Also I have another checkBox (`chkSetAllActive`).

**Problem:**
When I click this checkbox (`chkSetAllActive.Checked = true`) all dynamically created checkboxes (Active) are being checked  but when I want to uncheck all (`chkSetAllActive.Checked = false`) this dynamically created checkboxes stays checked. I guess there is some problem with dynamically created controls.

If anyone have some ideas I would be thankful.

here is also photo sample:

[image]

Comment: set `autoPostBack` true for checkbox `chkSetAllActive`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, remove the `box.Checked = ...` code from `CreateCheckBox`. It does not belong there. You will modify the Checked-state on postbacks even if the `chkSetAllActive`-CheckBox wasn't clicked.

You should handle the `CheckedChanged` event of the `chkSetAllActive` in this way:

```
var allChk = PlaceHolder1.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>()
    .Where(chk => chk.Text == "Active"); // to avoid problems
foreach(CheckBox chk in allChk)
    chk.Checked = chkSetAllActive.Checked;
```

**Edit**: non-LINQ

```
foreach(Control ctrl in PlaceHolder1.Controls)
{
    CheckBox chk = ctrl as CheckBox;
    if(chk != null && chk.Text == "Active")
        chk.Checked = chkSetAllActive.Checked;
}
```

Comment: .OfType<CheckBox>() It wont recognize this part

Comment: @MeMememe: you have to add `using System.Linq;`

Comment: Thanks for your answer but unfortunately I can't use LINQ. I'm using .NET 2.0(I guess I should mention that first, sorry) If you have alternative solution I would be really grateful.